# How do I select the next `td` in this `tr`?

Tags: xpath

I want to select the next sibling of a `td` tag in a `tr` element.

The `tr` element is this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Created On:</td>
  <td>06/28/2018 06:32      </td>
</tr>
```

My XPATH code looks like this: `//text()[contains(.,'Created On:')]`.

How do I select the next `td`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
//tr/td[text()="Created On:"]/following-sibling::td
```

[**Demo**](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ctr%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3ECreated%20On%3A%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%20%20%3Ctd%3E06%2F28%2F2018%2006%3A32%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3C%2Ftr%3E&=Created%20On%3A&extract=%2F%2Ftr%2Ftd%5Btext()%3D%22Created%20On%3A%22%5D%2Ffollowing-sibling%3A%3Atd&=%2F%2Ftr%2Ftd%5Btext()%3D%22Created%20On%3A%22%5D%2Ffollowing-sibling%3A%3Atd&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto)