# Scrapy: How do I select the next `td` in this `tr`?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to select the next sibling of a `td` tag in a `tr` element.

The `tr` element is this:

```
<tr>
  <td>Created On:</td>
  <td>06/28/2018 06:32      </td>
</tr>
```

My Scrapy code looks like this: `response.xpath("//text()[contains(.,'Created On:')]/following-sibling::td")`. But that gives me an empty list `[]`.

How do I select the next `td`?

Comment: You already got an answer in your [previous ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217794/how-do-i-select-the-next-td-in-this-tr). Why did you modify the solution to make it return you undesirable result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select the next \`td\` in this \`tr\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217794/how-do-i-select-the-next-td-in-this-tr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this XPath expression:

```
//text()[contains(.,'Created On:')]/../following-sibling::td
```

You were trying to use the `following-sibling` axis from the wrong context node. Going back one level fixes this problem.

An alternative is matching the `td` element in the first place like in this expression:

```
//td[contains(text(),'Created On:')]/following-sibling::td
```

Comment: After reading the comment from @Andersson I'm wondering why you asked this question in the first place...